# Where are the files downloaded using pip stored in virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip

I am on linux mint 12. I have created a virtualenv called `userena`. and then i installed [django-userena](http://django-userena.org/) using pip in that virtualenv. I need to edit some django-usrena files. Where are they located?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To see where your virtualenv files are, enable it and issue the following bash command:

```
$ echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

Similar to your system's Python installation, the packages are stored inside `lib/python2.*/site-packages/` directory. Find your package in there and edit the necessary files.

Answer (score 6):

You need to know the path to env userena, firstly. Then the installed app usually is in `path_to_userena/lib/python2.x/site-packages/`. Django apps normally does not contain prefix `django-`, thus `userena` here.

Or you could find it in Python by

```
import os.path, userena
os.path.dirname(userena.__file__)
```

Comment: thank you sir so much, i have a little issue, my virtualenv is actually called `userena-demo` and if i do `import os.path, userena-demo` it will show this error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` i think it's because of the `Dash` what to do in that case? do i have to rename the virtualenv? if yes, how to do so?

Comment: @user it's not the virtualenv name but the module you installed into it which you should be importing to use this approach.

Comment: @user As Charles described, `userena` here stands for the installed library `django-userena`

Answer (score 3):

You will find virtualenv at `home/.virtualenvs`. In the `.virtualenvs` directory you will find your virtualenv

Comment: This is the only answer that make sense

Answer (score 2):

if you're using virtualenvwrapper (which i recommend):

lets say that i'm using already in using the `foo` virtualenv and I have virtualenvwrapper installed:

```
$ cdvirtualenv
```

if this command i'll go to the `$VIRTUAL_ENV` path which in this case is:

```
$ pwd
/home/bernardo/.virtualenvs/foo
$ ls
bin  build  include  lib  local
```

in my case to see my virtualenv packages i'll go to `lib/python2.7/site-packages` or:

```
$ lssitepackages
figleaf  figleaf-0.6.1-py2.7.egg-info  initools  INITools-0.3.1-py2.7.egg-info
```

the commands `cdvirtualenv` and `lssitepackages` comes from "virtualenvwrapper"

Answer (score 1):

The packages you download using pip or any other method in a virtual env is stored in the virtual env folder i.e

Suppose you create a virtual environment ENV, so the downloaded packages will be inside ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

**Proof Positive location derivation of pipenv installed packages:**

*Get the install base with* '% pipenv --venv'

Run the install command a 2nd time, and pipenv will divulge the packages locations!

% pipenv install django djangorestframework pygments

1. Installing django... Requirement already satisfied: django in
   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg
   (2.1.1)
2. Requirement already satisfied: pytz in
   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytz-2018.5-py3.7.egg (from
   django) (2018.5)
3. Adding django to Pipfile's [packages]... Installing
   djangorestframework... Requirement already satisfied:
   djangorestframework in
   /Users/sww/.local/share/virtualenvs/env-YuUv1EZG/lib/python3.7/site-packages
   (3.8.2)
4. Adding djangorestframework to Pipfile's [packages]... Installing
   pygments... Requirement already satisfied: pygments in
   /Users/sww/.local/share/virtualenvs/env-YuUv1EZG/lib/python3.7/site-packages
   (2.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using anaconda on windows, there is a file environments.txt in the .conda folder at your users home directory